# pandas 'as_index' function doesn't work as expected

Tags: python, pandas

This is a minimum reproducible example of my original dataframe called 'calls':

```
       phone_number    call_outcome   agent  call_number
0      83473306392   NOT INTERESTED  orange            0
1     762850680150  CALL BACK LATER  orange            1
2     476309275079   NOT INTERESTED  orange            2
3     899921761538  CALL BACK LATER     red            3
4     906739234066  CALL BACK LATER  orange            4
```

Writing this pandas command...

```
most_calls = calls.groupby('agent') \
.count().sort('call_number', ascending=False)
```

Returns this...

```
           phone_number  call_outcome  call_number
agent                                          
orange          2234          2234         2234
red             1478          1478         1478
black            750           750          750
green            339           339          339
blue             199           199          199
```

Which is correct, but for the fact that I want 'agent' to be a variable and not indexed.

I've used the `as_index=False` function on numerous occasions and am  familiar with specifying `axis=1`. However in this instance it doesn't matter where or how I incorporate these parameters, every permutation returns an error.

These are some examples I've tried and the corresponding errors:

```
most_calls = calls.groupby('agent', as_index=False) \
.count().sort('call_number', ascending=False)

ValueError: invalid literal for long() with base 10: 'black'
```

And

```
most_calls = calls.groupby('agent', as_index=False, axis=1) \
.count().sort('call_number', ascending=False)

ValueError: as_index=False only valid for axis=0
```

Comment: So does `calls.groupby('agent').count().sort('call_number', ascending=False).reset_index()` do what you want?

Comment: The reason that `as_index` fails is because you call `count` which only works for numeric types

Comment: Useful information re numeric types.  And yes, `reset_index()` works perfectly!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that, irrespective of the `groupby` operation you've done, you just need to call [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) to say that the index column should just be a regular column.

Starting with a mockup of your data:

```
import pandas as pd
calls = pd.DataFrame({
    'agent': ['orange', 'red'],
    'phone_number': [2234, 1478],
    'call_outcome': [2234, 1478],
})
>> calls
    agent   call_outcome    phone_number
0   orange  2234    2234
1   red     1478    1478
```

here is the operation you did with `reset_index()` appended:

```
>> calls.groupby('agent').count().sort('phone_number', ascending=False).reset_index()
    agent   call_outcome    phone_number
0   orange  1   1
1   red     1   1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `reset_index` to move index to a normal column.

```
calls.groupby('agent').count().sort('call_number', ascending=False).reset_index()

Out[117]: 
      agent  phone_number  call_outcome  call_number
0    orange             4             4            4
1       red             1             1            1
```